# Implicit differentiation dx/dt?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to find $\frac{\partial t}{ \partial y}$ as a function of $x$, $y$ and $\frac{\partial t}{\partial x}$ if both $x$ and $y$ depend on $t$ for the function

```
f[x_]=Tan[x*y] + E^y = -10*x
```

but am uncertain as to how to do this. Any ideas or suggestions?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'll want to use `Dt`. You'll also want to compare the documentation for `=` and `==` to properly define equations.

Comment: D[Tan[x*y] + Exp[y] + 10*x, t, NonConstants -> {x, y}]
10*D[x, t, NonConstants -> {x, y}] + 
    Exp[y]*D[y, t, NonConstants -> {x, 
        y}] + (y*D[x, t, NonConstants -> {x, y}] + x*D[y, t, 
    NonConstants -> {x,
       y}])*(Sec[x*y])^2 /. D[x, t, NonConstants -> {x, y}] -> x'
Exp[y]*D[y, 
            t, NonConstants -> {x, y}] + 10*x' + (Sec[x*
                y])^2*(x*D[y, t, NonConstants -> {x, y}] + y*
              x') /. D[y, t, NonConstants -> {x, y}] -> y'
Solve[10*x' + Exp[y]*y' + (Sec[x*y])^2*(y*x' + x*y') == 0, y']

Is this correct?

Comment: How would I use Dt to solve this with respect to t? I have an exam on this tomorrow and would be SO grateful if you could explain!

Comment: The documentation explains explicitly how to use it. If you want the implicit derivative of an equation you simply apply it like a normal function, `Dt[Tan[x*y]+E^y==-10x,t]`.

Comment: If you have something to add to the question, please [edit] the question, code is very difficult to read in the comments, even worse if there is no effort to format it correctly.